# What has a time complexity of O(nlogk)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

To sort a basic array of integers of size *n* find the *k* smallest elements, what function would cause a time complexity of O(nlogk)?

When looking at a merge sort for example, it gives has the time complexity of O(nlogn). Where does *k* come into the time complexity?

Comment: You need to make a min heap of size k and insert the n elements in it. Insertion in heap will take log k time and for n elements I think it should give you the required nlogk

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan You want to be able to efficiently remove elements which aren't in the smallest k, so it should be a max-heap.

Answer (score 2):

Put the numbers into a priority queue one-by-one. Every time you insert a number, if the queue now has more than k elements, then remove the largest one. Finally, poll the elements remaining in the queue to get the k smallest from the original array, in reverse order.

This runs in O(n log k) time assuming your priority queue of size at most k+1 can insert and find-and-remove-max in O(log k) time. A heap or balanced BST will work.